# How can I use an if-condition for storing data into the database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a very strange problem. This is my update.php, which is storing the **user** and **date** in the database by clicking the submit button:

```
   <?php
    session_start();

    require('database.php'); 
    require('header.php');

    if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ 
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    } 

    $id = 0;
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];

    if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $animal = $_REQUEST['animal'];
    }

    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql1 = "UPDATE animals set user1 = ?, date1 = NOW() WHERE id = '$id'";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
    $q->execute(array($user));
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: index.php");                      
    } 
    ?>

    <form action="update.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>"/>
    <button type="submit"> Submit</button>
    </form>
```

It is working very well so far. But I need to make a condition, that means, only do the stuff if `$animal == 1`.

Now there comes my problem.

I simply put my if condition around my sql request:

```
if ($animal == 1){
    $sql1 = "UPDATE animals set user1 = ?, date1 = NOW() WHERE id = '$id'";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
}
```

I need this because later I also want to write:

```
   if ($animal == 2){
        $sql2 = "UPDATE animals set user2 = ?, date2 = NOW() WHERE id = '$id'";
                $q = $pdo->prepare($sql2);
    }
```

But it is simply not working. If I use the `if-condition`, then my code is just not working anymore, means nothing is stored in the database and also the redirect to index.php is not working. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Until now I found out that `$animal` will not be outputted inside `if ( !empty($_POST)) {...` but I still do not know how to get it there

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, I needed to write in the form:

```
action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>&m=<?php echo $animal; ?>
```